# BizTalk ESB Portal - Exception Handling

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.0

I am reasonably experienced in BizTalk but new to the ESB Tool kit.  We don't really have the need for an ESB solution as such but I would like to use the ESB Portal to display errors, modify messages and resubmit.

- I have successfully, as far as I can tell, installed and configured the ESB tool kit correctly on my dev machine.
- I have managed to send errors to the portal by enabling routing for failed messages and from within an Orchestration by creating a message thus: `FaultMessage = Microsoft.Practices.ESB.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionMgmt.CreateFaultMessage();`

The messages display correctly in the portal and on selecting 'Edit' I am given the option to resubmit via WCF OnRamp, SOAP OnRamp and HTTPReceive.  This is where my problem starts.  I have been using the WCF OnRamp to resubmit and on doing so I get a message:

> This message has been successfully resubmitted

However on returning to the home screen of the portal I now have a new error for the Microsoft.Practices.ESB application:

```
There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines.ItinerarySelectReceiveXml, Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "ESB Itinerary Selector" Receive Port: "OnRamp.Itinerary" URI: "/ESB.ItineraryServices.WCF/ProcessItinerary.svc" Reason: Error 135008: The itinerary was not found in the repository.
```

I presume I need to configure something here, a resolver perhaps for my message but I, so far, have not been able to find a guide that will help me through this issue.  Is there a walk through out there some where that shows the full end to end exception handling with ESB Portal?  I have managed to find plenty of help with getting messages into it but not for configuring for resubmit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCF OnRamp uses the ItinerarySelectReceiveXml pipeline this can be configured to point to an Itinerary or Business Rule and thus the message can be easily routed depending on its message type and content.
[image: Reroute errors via pipeline]

My issue now is that a third party got there before me on our installation so I am now looking into creating a new OnRamp and configuring the ESB portal to pick that up in its resubmit list.

Answer (score 5):

Coincidentally I was trying to make this work today as well...

If you set the Itinerary resolver connection string on the WCF OnRamp's receive pipeline component configuration to use ITINERARY-STATIC:\headerRequired=true; (instead of ITINERARY-STATIC:\headerRequired=false;), then you'll get the following message in the event viewer:

*The itinerary name is required and was not provided*

Meaning the Itinerary isn't present in the custom SOAP header.

I also traced the message going from the ESB.Portal using Fiddler (after turning off the Message security in both the ESB.Portal and the BizTalk receive location). No Itinerary custom SOAP header.

After going through the ESB.Portal code, I found the cause in MessageResubmitter.cs:

```
   [Serializable]
   public static class MessageResubmitter
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Submits an XML message to the WCF OnRamp.  The URL of the WCF OnRamp is defined in the
      /// portal web.config.  Context properties are not resubmitted, they are expected to be
      /// applied by the receiving pipeline.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="doc">The XML document to submit.</param>
      /// <returns>True if the submission was successful, false if the submission failed.</returns>
      public static bool ResubmitWCF(XmlDocument doc)
      {
         try
         {
            ProcessRequestClient onRamp = new ProcessRequestClient();
            onRamp.SubmitRequest(**null**, doc.OuterXml);
            return true;
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
```

The first argument of SubmitRequest is the Itinerary, which is set to null. This means the ESB.Portal does not resend the Itinerary as a custom SOAP header to BizTalk when you resubmit the message.

At the moment, I can think of the following options to make this work:
1) Create a (or modify the existing) generic WCF OnRamp to use the BRE to determine the Itinerary to be associated with the resubmitted message. This could however become complex, because you'll need to create your rules to be able to deal with any messages resubmitted from any step within your itineraries.
2) Modify the code of the ESB.Portal to be able to resend the Itinerary + current step as a Custom SOAP header.

I'm probably going for option 2.

Comment: Nice work, would be grateful to see how you finally resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue recently. While we were exporting our itineraries to a local database, and deploying them, the ESB would not be able to find the itineraries.

It turned out a consultant we had on site had modified the esb.config file in ESB Toolkit to look for itineraries on a server instead of the local machine.

So, if, like me, you are sure the itineraries are being exported to the right place and that they are deployed, modify the esb.config connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ItineraryDb" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EsbItineraryDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionString>
```